# android drag list adapter item to n drop into bin

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, swipe-gesture

I would like to implement a list activity where user can drag an item from a list view and then i would like to show a small recycle bin where user can drop the selected item. Recycle bin can appear from side or bottom of the screen or just pop out. This recycle bin should disappear if user drops an item.

How do i make it possible?

Answer (score 0):

#ProTip : Starting by searching the official doc sometimes yield interesting results, like finding a documentation : 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html